# Avoid Re-Render of Component on State update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have Video page in react native where I update time every seconds using setState, so my page re-renders Every seconds.

I use Functional Component.How do I avoid Render of certain component inside my main return statement.

```
    const App = () =>
    {
    return (
    <View>
      <View>
      <VideoPlayer/>
      </View>
      <RefreshList url={item.url} />
    </View>
    )
   }
```

So basically Above code is rendering Refreslist component every seconds.I tried googling and found Memo , So I tried something like below

```
  const Memoized = React.memo((props) => {
    return (
              <RefreshList url={item.url} />
    );
  });
```

And then inside the app

```
  const App = () =>
        {
        return (
        <View>
          <View>
          <VideoPlayer/>
          </View>
          <Memoized/>
        </View>
        )
       }
```

Still my component RefreshList is rendered every second on state change.

Comment: does `item.url` also change every x seconds?

Comment: No , even if I remove the url props , its still rendering multiple times.

Comment: Please make full reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), where the actual state is? Is it in `RefreshList`? Update your question

Comment: Can you post complete code of <Memoized/> ?

Comment: I will update example in sometime..actual state is in app...Refreshlist is just simple component with text..basically app refresh every seconds along with Refreshlist component

Comment: do you really need to update every second using setState?

Comment: Basically I am displaying duration of video in a component.. I solved the issue by seperating components in different JS files.